# change persian date to gregorian date and vice versa

Tags: c#, asp.net, date

I used the following code in order to change Persian date to Gregorian date. for example it changes 1393/05/05 to 2014/05/26.

```
                    if (MultiView6.ActiveViewIndex == 1)
                    {

                        date = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text);
                        string change = date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
                        int day1 = Convert.ToInt32(change.Substring(8, 2));
                        int mon1 = Convert.ToInt32(change.Substring(5, 2));
                        int year1 = Convert.ToInt32(change.Substring(0, 4));
                        PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();
                        change = (pc.ToDateTime(year1, mon1, day1, 0, 0, 0, 0).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd").Substring(0, 10));
                        date = Convert.ToDateTime(change);
                    }
```

however for some special dates such as 1393/02/29 the code stops working and I receive the above error from the first line of my code:

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

I suppose I would have the same problem if I want to convert 2014/05/19 to Persian date (which is 1393/02/29)....
is there a way to fix this error?

Comment: Why do you convert a DateTime to String and then back to DateTime here: `DateTime.Parse(d1.ToString())`?

Comment: if I omit that part it won't give me the yyyy/mm/dd format which I need for my website

Comment: No, you just need `d1.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")`. If your current culture has a different date separator but you want to enforce `/`, you have to use `InvariantCulture`: `d1.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: You can't convert the current year to a Persian year and then use it to create a non-Persian DateTime. The year 1393 in the Gregorian calendar is not a leap year, which is why you are getting that error.

Comment: I get the error from the first line:   date = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text);

Comment: this is not a leap year for us neither

Comment: [The right way to convert is documented by Microsoft in the online help for class PersianCalendar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.persiancalendar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: it won't show the right way of converting these two date....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to use constructor accepting `Calendar` - [DateTime(int year, int month, int day, Calendar calendar)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk65c9c1.aspx).

```
string persianDateString = "1393/02/29";
string[] persianDateParts = persianDateString.Split('/');
int persianYear = int.Parse(persianDateParts[0]);
int persianMonth = int.Parse(persianDateParts[1]);
int persianDay = int.Parse(persianDateParts[2]);
PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();
DateTime date = new DateTime(persianYear, persianMonth, persianDay, pc);
```

Answer (score 2):

`year`, `month` and `day` are in `PersianCalendar` and you can't use them in `DateTime`. if you want to convert from `PersianCalendar` to `DateTime`, you have to do this:

```
DateTime d1=p.ToDateTime(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

=====================================================

in your new code you have another mistake. variables `day1`, `mon1` and `year1` are in Gregorian calendar and you can't use them in `PersianCalendar.ToDateTime()`.

Comment: this helped in some way but I still get an error from the first line of my code...I edited the code in a new one...could u review it?

Comment: @sara.y yes you will, as people have said it wont convert a persian date string to a DateTime object/

Comment: so there is not any other way to change the Persian date to Gregorian?...I should code this myself?